# Call subform's (datasheet) Click event?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've had good success calling subform click events when pointing to a control.

I am currently using datasheet as a subform `Forms!mainform!InvList_subform`.  The on-click event works as expected when clicking the subform's datasheet record selector.

I'd like to also call the datasheets on-click event from another event on another subform (AcctList_subform) but cannot quite get the syntax working.

From the AcctList_subform, I've tried variants like the following without success:

```
Forms!mainform!InvList_subform.Form.Click
Forms!mainform!InvList_subform.Form_Click
Forms!mainform!InvList_subform.Click
Forms!mainform!InvList_subform.Form.Form_Click
```

What is the correct form, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must change the sub modifier from `private` to `public` if you are going to access it from outside the form. in your case `Public Sub Form_Click()`

Comment: Thanks Krish.  Changed to "Public", but still getting hung up on syntax, I think.  Also tried to changeover the datasheet's "Click" event to an "OnCurrent" event.  Same issues.

Comment: you say this is not working? `Forms!mainform!InvList_subform.Form_Click`

Comment: OK, got it!     Forms!mainform!InvList_subform.Form.Form_Current

Comment: This is one of the few ways to get a subform datasheet to respond to a mainform event! Thanks.